# Is there any way to write a for loop in python which will grab images from camera and save it parallelly?

Tags: python, image-processing, parallel-processing, buffer, frame-rate

I'm using a basler camera to take images and also using pypylon to interface camera software(pylon) with python

I want to create two parts

1. grab images (i.e 1000 or 2000)with some specific exposure time and shutter speed.
2. and save it parallelly without disturbing fps.

   Or is there any way to save them in a buffer and use it afterward which won't affect fps?

Right now my concern is to save images without affecting fps
Thanks

Following is my code

```
import pypylon
pypylon.pylon_version.version
available_cameras = pypylon.factory.find_devices()
available_cameras
cam = pypylon.factory.create_device(available_cameras[0])
cam.opened
cam.open()

cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRateEnable'] = True
cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRate'] = 1000
cam.properties['ExposureTime']
cam.properties['ExposureTime'] = 1000
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imsave 
count=0
for image in cam.grab_images(30):
    count +=1
    a=str(count)
    b=str('I:/'+ a+'.png')
    imsave(b,image)
```

Comment: How are you getting those images? Could you provide some sample code so that we can see roughly what you're doing?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm using a basler camera to take images and also using pypylon to interface camera software(pylon) with python. I updated my code in my question please check above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: `scipy`'s `imsave` has been deprecated, and is scheduled to be removed. Use `imageio`'s [`imwrite`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html#imageio.imwrite) instead.

Now for the code. There are a few ways of doing this. I'll move from fewest modifications to most modifications.

### Fix up code

I'm just going to make some changes to your program, to make it easier to modify later and so that it won't break in the future:

```
import pypylon
from imageio import imwrite

available_cameras = pypylon.factory.find_devices()
cam = pypylon.factory.create_device(available_cameras[0])
cam.open()

cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRateEnable'] = True
cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRate'] = 1000
cam.properties['ExposureTime'] = 1000

for count, image in enumerate(cam.grab_images(30)):
    filename = str('I:/{}.png'.format(count))
    imwrite(filename, image)
```

Future modifications will be based on this. I recommend looking up what some of these do, like `'ExposureTime'`, since it looks like you blindly copied these from the example.

### Buffer

In order to store these images in a buffer, we can simply read them all straight away by converting the iterable into a `tuple` (a read-only list). Once we're done with the buffer we can `del`ete it to free up some memory.

```
import pypylon
from imageio import imwrite

available_cameras = pypylon.factory.find_devices()
cam = pypylon.factory.create_device(available_cameras[0])
cam.open()

cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRateEnable'] = True
cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRate'] = 1000
cam.properties['ExposureTime'] = 1000

buffer = tuple(cam.grab_images(30))
for count, image in enumerate(buffer):
    filename = str('I:/{}.png'.format(count))
    imwrite(filename, image)
del buffer
```

### Asynchronous saving

I need to do something with multiprocessing. Oh, look, there's a Python module called [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). I've never used this before, but by reading it I can create this:

```
import pypylon
from imageio import imwrite
from multiprocessing import Pool

def save_image(pair):
    count, image = pair  # pair is actually two values
    filename = str('I:/{}.png'.format(count))
    imwrite(filename, image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    available_cameras = pypylon.factory.find_devices()
    cam = pypylon.factory.create_device(available_cameras[0])
    cam.open()

    cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRateEnable'] = True
    cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRate'] = 1000
    cam.properties['ExposureTime'] = 1000

    with Pool(30) as p:  # One for each image
        p.map(save_image, enumerate(cam.grab_images(30)))
```

This solution is the one you asked for in the title. The most cryptic part of this is `pair`. This is there because each item generated by `enumerate` is a tuple of the form `(i, image)`. This is only one argument, so it's passed to `save_image` as one argument. We need to expand that into the two variables `count` and `image` so that the rest of the code will work, which is what the first line of the function achieves.

You might also have noticed `if __name__ == "__main__":`. This makes sure that the code only runs when the program is imported as a module, which is used internally by `multiprocess` to find the `save_image` function.

I hope this does what you wanted. If you want clarification, feel free to post a comment. If you have a separate question, please ask another question.

Comment: Thank you very much @wizzwizz4

Comment: @Rishabhsharma You double-clicked the accept mark, which accepts and then unaccepts. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: no, I did that accidentally. Really sorry for that. I'll try your code on my camera and let you know if it worked or not and then accept the answer.

Comment: @Rishabhsharma Good! Some people accept answers before making sure that they're right; you're waiting until you know whether it's right before deciding to accept an answer which is what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help. All three of codes are running well for capturing 30 images. But when I'm running third one 'Asynchronous saving' for 2000 images (30 is replaced with 2000 in "with Pool(30) as p" and "p.map(save_image, enumerate(cam.grab_images(30)))") it's giving some error which is: OSError: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. I think it's a memory error. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @Rishabhsharma Install more RAM or increase the page file size. See [this image](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/comment/1741165/pagingfiletoosmall.jpg); that was 17 threads I think. It's probably better to use one of the other techniques, if you can. Your computer (basically) just ran out of memory because it was (sort of) creating 30 copies of your program in memory (plus the original), each of which was dealing with a separate image (except the original, which was waiting for them all to finish).

Comment: it worked but taking a long time. last question: From following how above programme(Buffer and Asynchronous saving) is taking images: (1) capturing the first image...saving the first image.... capturing the second image.....saving the second image... and so on to N images (2) capturing all frames till N images..saving all frames in last ?

Comment: @Rishabhsharma Saving images onto the disk is much slower than saving them in memory. See [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://i.imgur.com/k0t1e.png). So the buffer program saves them in all in a list, then writes them one by one into files, which is closer to (2). The asynchronous one is similar to (2) in a way, but it tries to save them all at the same time and it's harder to see where they're stored (but they're still stored in memory).

Comment: If this answer worked, could you please accept it? That will give me a "prize" of 15 reputation points for getting the right answer, as well as marking the question as answered.

Comment: absolutely, Don't worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rishabhsharma You're welcome! If you are ever really stuck again, feel free to give me a link to your question. I can't promise I'll be able to help, but I'll have a look.

Comment: how can I message you personally? I have one more question.

Comment: @Rishabhsharma There's no such feature; somebody else will probably have the same question in future and it wastes a lot of time having to constantly re-answer questions in private messages that don't show up on search engines. You can post a link to it here though.

Comment: I just want to make video instead of taking pictures by using that buffer code. I tried to modify but didn't worked. Do you want me to make a another question or you can solve it here ?

Comment: @Rishabhsharma Please make another question! If you post a link here quickly after asking I'll help you to edit it to be clearer to avoid downvotes if it needs it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782358/save-video-instead-of-saving-images-while-using-basler-camera-and-python