# Save video instead of saving images while using basler camera and python

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm using Basler camera and python to record some video. I can successfully capture individual frames, but I don't know how to record a video.

Following is my code:

```
import os
import pypylon
from imageio import imwrite
import time
start=time.time()

print('Sampling rate (Hz):')
fsamp = input()
fsamp = float(fsamp)

time_exposure = 1000000*(1/fsamp)

available_cameras = pypylon.factory.find_devices()
cam = pypylon.factory.create_device(available_cameras[0])
cam.open()

#cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRateEnable'] = True
#cam.properties['AcquisitionFrameRate'] = 1000
cam.properties['ExposureTime'] = time_exposure

buffer = tuple(cam.grab_images(2000))
for count, image in enumerate(buffer):
    filename = str('I:/Example/{}.png'.format(count))
    imwrite(filename, image)
del buffer
```

Comment: I've submitted a suggested edit to make what you're asking clearer in the question body. (It also shows that you're not just dumping code, but instead providing your attempt.) Could you review it?

Comment: [Here is the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19405176); the reviewer thought the changes I was making were too drastic (and I don't blame them) but if you think that they are OK you can choose to apply the edit by clicking the Accept button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a way to record a video using `pypylon`; it seems to be a pretty light wrapper around Pylon. However, I have found a way to save a video using `imageio`:

```
from imageio import get_writer
with get_writer('I:/output-filename.mp4', fps=fps) as writer:
    # Some stuff with the frames
```

The above can be used with `.mov`, `.avi`, `.mpg`, `.mpeg`, `.mp4`, `.mkv` or `.wmv`, so long as the FFmpeg program is available. How you will install this program depends on your operating system. See this link for [details on the parameters you can use](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_ffmpeg.html#parameters-for-saving).

Then, simply replace the call to `imwrite` with:

```
writer.append_data(image)
```

ensuring that this occurs in the `with` block.

An example implementation:

```
import os
import pypylon
from imageio import get_writer

while True:
    try:
        fsamp = float(input('Sampling rate (Hz): '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input.')

time_exposure = 1000000 / fsamp

available_cameras = pypylon.factory.find_devices()
cam = pypylon.factory.create_device(available_cameras[0])
cam.open()

cam.properties['ExposureTime'] = time_exposure

buffer = tuple(cam.grab_images(2000))
with get_writer(
       'I:/output-filename.mkv',  # mkv players often support H.264
        fps=fsamp,  # FPS is in units Hz; should be real-time.
        codec='libx264',  # When used properly, this is basically
                          # "PNG for video" (i.e. lossless)
        quality=None,  # disables variable compression
        pixelformat='rgb24',  # keep it as RGB colours
        ffmpeg_params=[  # compatibility with older library versions
            '-preset',  # set to faster, veryfast, superfast, ultrafast
            'fast',     # for higher speed but worse compression
            '-crf',  # quality; set to 0 for lossless, but keep in mind
            '11'     # that the camera probably adds static anyway
        ]
) as writer:
    for image in buffer:
        writer.append_data(image)
del buffer
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow (within 20 hours) and let you know thank you

Comment: Not working !!! TypeError: _open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_params'

Comment: @Rishabhsharma Try replacing `output_params` with `ffmpeg_params`; you might have an older version of `imageio`.

Comment: Make sure that you have FFmpeg installed; you can try running `import imageio;imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()` in the Python Shell if you can't work out how to install it.

Comment: Yeah i installed it

Comment: hi, if i want to improve the quality of video, what are the perimeters i should change in above code ? I set quality as 10 but still quality is not that much good.

Comment: @Rishabhsharma See the comment; set to 0 for lossless. Remember that setting the exposure settings etc. on the camera is important to reduce static.